# Size of smallest feature from pixel depth resolution

Tags: computer-vision, cameras, stereo-vision

How do I get the size in mm of the smallest feature a depth camera can detect?

Known variables are: distance from the target (for instance 1 meter), depth resolution in pixels (for instance 1280 x 720) and depth Field of view angles (for instance H=90°, V=60°).

This [resource](http://robotsforroboticists.com/camera-lens-selection/) mentions the relation between minimum feature size and pixel resolution for the 2D RGB case.